# Return Image base 64 without saving the file in hard drive, using puppeteersharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am using puppeteersharp to converting HTML to image:

https://www.puppeteersharp.com/examples/index.html

This is getting the HTMl and save the image, then I am going to return base64 image, I am looking to return image base64 without saving it in hard drive.

This is the code:

```
          await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
           var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true
        });
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

        await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions
        {
            Width = 750,
            Height = 750,
        });

        await page.SetContentAsync("<h2>Test</h2>");
        await page.ScreenshotAsync(@"/Users/myname/Documents/puppeteertests/test1.jpg");

        byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"/Users/myname/Documents/puppeteertests/test1.jpg");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

Comment: ScreenshotStreamAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking something like this should probably work -
It takes the Stream that gets returned by the 'ScreenshotStreamAsync' method of the page and copies it to a MemoryStream so that we can get a byte array out of it really simply and pass that byte array to the Convert.ToBase64String

```
var thing =  await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
        var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false
        });
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

        await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions
        {
            Width = 750,
            Height = 750,
        });

        await page.SetContentAsync("<h2>Test</h2>");
        await page.ScreenshotAsync(@"test1.jpg");

        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
           page.ScreenshotStreamAsync().Result.CopyTo(memStream);
           var mything = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
           Console.WriteLine(mything);
        }
```